# Current transformer datasheet: confusion on turns ratio vs. max. rated currents

Tags: current-transformer

I have a SCT-013-000 current transformer that says it scales 100A:50mA, meaning it has a turns ratio of 1:2000, but the data sheet says that the turns ratio is 1:1800.

I'm pretty sure the turns ratio is 1:2000 but are there any test I could do to check?

Relevant part of the datasheet:

[image: Relevant part of the datasheet]

http://statics3.seeedstudio.com/assets/file/bazaar/product/101990029-SCT-013-000-Datasheet.pdf

Comment: it doesnt say it scales 100A to 50mA, it states those as rated limits.... i.e. max output current is 50mA and max input is 100A. I'd say that data sheet is correct and the ratio is indeed 1:1800...

Answer (score 4):

The DS says the rated input is 0 to 100 amps and independantly (on a seperate line) it says the rated output is 0 to 50 mA. You should take the turns ratio as being 1:1800 as stated in the DS and not assume that at full rated primary current (100 amps) the device will output 50 mA.

Magnetic core saturation (or rather the onset of core non-linearities) will take the maximum current down a shade or two from 55.5 mA to 50 mA. You could reasonably expect that with a primary current of  50 amps the output will be much closer to 1:1800 than at 100 amps primary current.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75594/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-current-transformer-turns-ratio).